# Is it possible on monogame to load content files to the Content Manager at run time?

Tags: monogame

The reason I want to do this is that I'd like users to be able to create their own racetrack and save it as an image. Users would then be able to select their image and race on their track.

I'm thinking of using the following code to test if the file exists

```
using System.IO;

public static bool TrackExists(string fileName)
    {
        return File.Exists($@"Content\Tracks\{fileName}.xnb");
    }
```

If it doesn't exist in the pipeline, I'd like it to be added and built so it can then be used in the project.

How should I go about doing this?

```
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            tex.FromFile(_graphicsDevice, path);   
       
            _game.ChangeState(new RaceState(_game, _graphicsDevice, _content, tex));
        }
```

Comment: The external file you want... is it an image (Texture2D)?

Comment: I would advise you not to allow end-users to add/edit the files in Content Pipeline. Whatever your file type is, you need to open it without using the content pipeline. Your file might take a bit longer to load, but that is the only way you should be doing it.

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy Yes

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy, can I ask how come? I'm planning on having a way of validating the image that has been made so it should not break anything

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load an image file as a Texture2D, you need to use the static method `Texture2D.FromFile()` as follows

```cs
myTex2D = Texture2D.FromFile(GraphicsDevice, "path/to/file");
```

As a rule of thumb, you cannot use the pipeline to load files dynamically. Nevertheless, it is not necessary that you have to use it. AFAIK the pipeline is the best and fastest way to load the **static content** of your game. There will be methods to import your custom files as content dynamically, so don't worry just because you're not using the pipeline. There are many types in Monogame (like Texture2D) that support dynamic loading from files.

EDIT:
Just to clarify, The method is a **static** member of `Texture2D` class, so you should be using it as follows:

```cs
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        tex = Texture2D.FromFile(_graphicsDevice, path);
        //...Rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: @DanCook Glad to help. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to find that method but it doesn't appear when I type. Do u have any suggestions?

Comment: I've edited the post to show the code I've added, VS says Rexture2D doesn't contain a definition for FromFile()

Comment: @DanCook I edited my answer. It should be clear now. The method needs to be called via `Texture2D` as it is static.